# Conditional Assignment Operator Issue in Part 2 of Refactor Factory in Ruby Class in Code Academy

Tags: ruby, refactoring, conditional-statements

I'm given this code to refactor:

```
$VERBOSE = nil    # We'll explain this at the end of the lesson.
require 'prime'   # This is a module. We'll cover these soon!

def first_n_primes(n)

  unless n.is_a? Integer
    return "n must be an integer."
  end

  if n <= 0
    return "n must be greater than 0."
  end

  prime_array = [] if prime_array.nil?

  prime = Prime.new
  for num in (1..n)
    prime_array.push(prime.next)
  end
  return prime_array
end

first_n_primes(10)
```

I'm told to remove the if statement in line 14 (the prime_array assignment) and replace it with a conditional assignment operator instead. Here is my amended code:

```
$VERBOSE = nil    # We'll explain this at the end of the lesson.
require 'prime'   # This is a module. We'll cover these soon!

def first_n_primes(n)

  unless n.is_a? Integer
    return "n must be an integer."
  end

  if n <= 0
    return "n must be greater than 0."
  end

  prime_array ||= [] 

  prime = Prime.new
  for num in (1..n)
    prime_array.push(prime.next)
  end
  return prime_array
end

first_n_primes(10)
```

However, when I compile this, even though the prime array generated seems indistinguishable from the one generated before, I still get the error: 
"Oops, try again. It looks like you didn't correctly use the conditional assignment operator in your code. Check the Hint if you need help!" with the hint not garnering any useful information beyond what I have already implemented.

What gives?

Note: I am not sure if this question is a good fit for stackoverflow or rather codereview. 
The fact that it is dealing with a specific operator suggests the former while the fact that it involves refactoring suggests the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've placed a whitespace character after `[]` in line 14...
With the space present it doesn't work for me as well, without one - it does.

So it's not your fault, it's theirs.

Comment: Thanks, it compiled correctly now! What a baffling bug on their part. I wish I had enough reputation points to upvote you but hopefully someone else will. Also, can someone explain why I was downvoted. I did try to find an equivalent question but could not. If someone has a link showing me such a question, I would happily apologise.

Comment: No problem, thank you for accepting the answer. Most people here are either carrying deeply for the level of the community, or pretty snobby. It's easy to get downvoted or, e.g. have proper answer removed by another before it's even read by the person asking. I don't think changing whole community is possible, so I'm taking my time to understand what this place is all about.

About your question: either someone thought that it fits some other Stack Exchange site, found it more proper to ask Code Academy (because you made no mistake and your code is interpretable) or simply didn't like it.

Comment: Yeah in retrospect I should have consulted the Code Academy forum first as they had this problem answered so I can see if they were coming from that point of view.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$VERBOSE = nil    # We'll explain this at the end of the lesson.
require 'prime'   # This is a module. We'll cover these soon!

def first_n_primes(n)

  unless n.is_a? Integer
    return "n must be an integer."
  end

  if n <= 0
    return "n must be greater than 0."
  end
  
  prime_array ||= [] 
  
  prime = Prime.new
  for num in (1..n)
    prime_array.push(prime.next)
  end
  return prime_array
end

first_n_primes(10)
```

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?

Comment: We can use conditional assignment to set prime_array to [] rather than bother with the .nil? check.